# pandas replace_if using chains

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I am trying to write a `dplyr/magrittr` like chain operation in pandas where one step includes a replace if command.

in R this would be:

```
mtcars %>%
     mutate(mpg=replace(mpg, cyl==4, -99)) %>%
     as.data.frame()
```

in python, I can do the following:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeccaLehn/4e06d2575eb9589dbe8c365d61cb056c/raw/64f1660f38ef523b2a1a13be77b002b98665cdfe/mtcars.csv')\
         .rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'brand'}, inplace=True)
data.loc[df.cyl == 4, 'mpg'] = -99
```

but would much prefer if this could be part of a chain. I could not find any `replace` alternative for pandas, which puzzles me. I am looking for something like:

```
data = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeccaLehn/4e06d2575eb9589dbe8c365d61cb056c/raw/64f1660f38ef523b2a1a13be77b002b98665cdfe/mtcars.csv')\
         .rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'brand'}, inplace=True) \
         .replace_if(...)
```

Comment: uses `Series.where` or `numpy.where` with `DataFrame.assign`

Comment: also, don't use `inplace=True` in a chain.

Comment: How will `where` or `assign` will work here with a chain? Because the read happens on the same operation it's difficult to reference the things you need. In this situation I think the want to chain complicates this operation far more than splitting it out.

Comment: @ALollz with `lambda`..? And using `mask`. Chaining on like `.assign(mpg = lambda x: x['mpg'].mask(x['cyl'] == 4, -99))`

Comment: or even simpler `.assign(mpg = lambda x: np.where(x.cyl == 4,-99 , x.mpg ))`

Comment: @ChrisA feel free to add as an answer

Comment: No need, this was @PaulH solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple to do in a chain.  Make sure you don't use `inplace=` in a chain as it does not return a data frame to next thing in chain

```
(pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ZeccaLehn/4e06d2575eb9589dbe8c365d61cb056c/raw/64f1660f38ef523b2a1a13be77b002b98665cdfe/mtcars.csv')
    .rename(columns={'Unnamed: 0':'brand'})
    .assign(mpg=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["cyl"]==4, -99, dfa["mpg"]))
)
```